# Plugin for Notepad++ 5.8.6 to list bookmarks of current file

Tags: plugins, notepad++, text-editors, bookmarks

Is there a plug-in for Notepad++ 5.8.6 (the last version before the huge ugly Find dialog!) to list all bookmarks set for current tab in a dockable window?

The user should be able to jump to any bookmark by clicking it in the list, similar to OpenCTags or SourceCookifier. Any other operations are optional.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [Named Bookmark](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/npp_plugins/bookmarkhelp.html) plugin that can help you to list bookmarks in a drop down. If you don't like to use any plugins you can actually make use of Sessions, which obviously doesn't list the bookmarks but at least saves them when you open it the next time. I have written about both of these approaches in my blog and you can read it [here](http://www.articpost.com/notepad-plugin-to-list-bookmarks/).