# How to get a bookmarks list?

Tags: notepad++

The bookmarks options in Notepad++(I'm using version 6.0) are okay, but their usefulness is limited by the fact that there is no way (that I can find) of getting a list of the existing bookmarks, so that I can jump to the one that I actually want.

This is an important feature to be missing, a fact that I personally find rather odd! I looked through the installed plug-ins, but don't see anything related to enhanced bookmarks. Is there any way to get this capability in Notepad++?

Comment: Possibly connected/duplicate <http://superuser.com/questions/392361/plugin-for-notepad-5-8-6-to-list-bookmarks-of-current-file>

Comment: Interesting, yes, this *is* a duplicate of that topic, which *also* never got any responses...

So, is there any possibility of getting this issue fixed?

Comment: Yes people have been looking for it. See this http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/3464977

Comment: Well, actually, 331753 is *not* the same topic; that thread is discussing *saving/restoring* bookmarks, my thread (and the duplicate un-responded-to thread) are discussing having a *list* of existing bookmarks, so user can select which bookmark they want to jump to, instead of being limited to previous/next.

Anyway, I hope you are correct that people are looking into it; I used bookmarks extensively in my day-to-day work, and Notepad++ simply is not useable without them, no matter how much I otherwise like the program...

Comment: That's right, Daniel. After not getting any answers, I tried writing my own plugin, but didn't get far. The Notepad++ source code header file Notepad_plus.h has a function *bool bookmarkPresent(int lineno)* which uses *ScintillaEditView *_pEditView* which I couldn't find a way to access from my plugin.

Comment: See this answer and vote for it! [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14099960/1967573][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14099960/1967573

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but this limitation still exists in Notepad++. Besides Sri Varshan's  suggestion, another option is to use a plugin named **NPPTaskList**, which can be downloaded [here](https://code.google.com/p/npp-task-list/downloads/detail?name=NPPTaskListV2.zip&can=2&q=). It is designed to work like a to-do list but can work nicely as a bookmark list as well. Just install it like any other Notepad++ plugin and edit the *npp_task_list.cfg* file to use whatever "$" patterns you want; the default looks like this:

> version=
>   1
>
> keywords=
>   $TODO:
>   $NOTE:
>   $HACK:
>   $REVIEW:

Any line that includes one of the above keywords (really the pattern sequence that begins with "$") will be included in the Task List, which is a sidebar. For example if you are coding in VB and enter this line:

> REM $NOTE: This is a "bookmarked" line of code.

... it will show up in the Task List as:

> $NOTE: This is a "bookmarked" line of code.

You can use these to navigate around your document by double-clicking them in the Task List.

I haven't tested this plugin extensively but so far it seems stable.

Comment: Looks promising, but in Notepad++ v7.5.1 this plugin causes npp to crash whenever I use this...

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Named Bookmark](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/npp_plugins/bookmarkhelp.html) plugin that can help you to list bookmarks in a drop down. If you don't like to use any plugins you can actually make use of Sessions, which obviously doesn't list the bookmarks but at least saves them when you open it the next time. I have written about both of these approaches in my blog and you can read it [here](http://www.articpost.com/notepad-plugin-to-list-bookmarks/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the objectives and the workflow it's possible to create an alternative menu for internal navigation across a file with the help of either of 2 plugins, in fact 3, but i found *SourceCookifier* to be heavy on the program, so may not be recommended.

These are ***TagsVew*** and ***LocationNavigate***. The first creates a tree of code tags present in a file, so one can add tags with names at certain places to have them listed in the tree and be able to access them at will. The second one allows recording cursor placements at different locations within the file and then navigating between them using the list of recorded locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the bookmark lines to new tab, using `Search -> Bookmark -> Copy Bookmarked Lines`

[image: Copy Bookmarked Lines]